# Converting search method to search string lists

Tags: python, search, depth-first-search

For this DFS function, i'm trying to convert it so I can use string lists instead of ints, but i'm not sure how to go about this. I tried changing the if(not visited[v]): lines to 'if v not in visited' to work with strings but I run into multiple errors. Right now the function still takes int list but I commented the changes i've attempted to make. What else would I have to change in order for the function to search?

```
def dfs(l1, x):
stack = []
stack.append(x)
n = len(l1)
visited = []
for i in range(0,n):
    visited.append(False)

while(len(stack)>0):
    v = stack.pop()
    if(not visited[v]):  #if v not in visited
        visited[v] = True #Problem with boolean 
        print(v, " ", end='')

        stack_aux = []
        for w in l1[v]:         #for w in l1
            if(not visited[w]): #if w not in visited
                stack_aux.append(w) 
        while(len(stack_aux)>0):
            stack.append(stack_aux.pop())
```

## ------------------------------------------------------------------

l1 = [ ['1','2','3'], ['4'], ['5','6'], ['7','8'], [''], ['9','10', '11'], ['12','13','14'], [''], [''] , [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], ['']]

Comment: You will need to convert them to `int`, so you can use them as an index, so just convert to `int()` when you append to the stack. Your code is still more complicated than it needs to be - you really don't need `stack_aux`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are operating on a dictionary vs. a list, with the values being keys in that dictionary then it is pretty simple to change the code to handle strings. Note: changed to a `yield` instead of print, this just yields the list of nodes:

```
def dfs_iterative(adjLists, s):
    stack = [s]
    visited = set()

    while stack:
        v = stack.pop()
        if v in visited:
            continue

        visited.add(v)
        yield v
        for w in adjLists.get(v, []):
            stack.append(w)

>>> adjLists1 = {'0':['1','2','3'], '1':['4'], '2':['5','6'], '3':['7','8'], '4':[], 
...              '5':['9','10','11'], '6':['12','13','14'], '7':[], '8':[]}
>>> list(dfs_iterative(adjLists1, '2'))
['2', '6', '14', '13', '12', '5', '11', '10', '9']
>>> ' '.join(dfs_iterative(adjLists1, '2'))
'2 6 14 13 12 5 11 10 9'
```

Note: changed to a yield